# Filter max number in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to filter and get max result in pyspark? I tried this below but it only gets me rows with rownum less than 2.

```
df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("SID", "Start Date", "End Date").orderBy("SID"))).filter(col("rownum")<2).orderBy("SID").drop("rownum")
```

I have this dataframe below.

```
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|SID     |StartDate |EndDate   |CID     |Date Added|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|1001    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002    |2021-03-22|
|1001    |2021-03-31|2021-03-31|1002    |2021-03-22|
|1004    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003    |2021-03-22|
|1005    |2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006    |2021-03-22|
|1001    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002    |2021-03-30|
|1001    |2021-03-31|2021-03-31|1006    |2021-03-30|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

This is my expected result.

```
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|SID     |StartDate |EndDate   |CID     |Date Added|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|1004    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003    |2021-03-22|
|1005    |2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006    |2021-03-22|
|1001    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002    |2021-03-30|
|1001    |2021-03-31|2021-03-31|1006    |2021-03-30|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some column names in your code do not exist, but I guess you probably wanted to order by the `CID` and `Date Added` columns in descending order if you want to get the latest value:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "rownum", 
    F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy("SID", "StartDate", "EndDate")
              .orderBy(F.desc("CID"), F.desc("DateAdded"))
    )
).filter(F.col("rownum")<2).orderBy("DateAdded").drop("rownum")

df2.show()
+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
| SID| StartDate|   EndDate| CID| DateAdded|
+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
|1005|2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006|2021-03-22|
|1004|2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003|2021-03-22|
|1001|2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002|2021-03-30|
|1001|2021-03-31|2021-03-31|1006|2021-03-30|
+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
```